# Error while navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

When I navigate to another view controller with y=this two lines it works ok.

```
  Inventory *obj = [[Inventory alloc] initWithNibName:@"Inventory" bundle:nil]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

But if i write this line [Which we must write]

```
[obj release];
```

It gives me bad access error.

Pls help.

Thanks

Comment: 1)Use Arc

2)Where are you writing the `[obj release];` ?

Comment: You mean auto release? I m not useing ARC.

Comment: Agreed. If you put `[obj release]` right after the `pushViewController`, then the object will have a +1 `retainCount` (because the `pushViewController` will retain it for you) and when you later `popViewController`, it will be appropriately be cleaned up for you.

Comment: same question here where are you release? before inserting nav controller or after?

Comment: `release` immediately after the `pushViewController`.

Comment: Inventory *obj = [[Inventory alloc] initWithNibName:@"Inventory" bundle:nil]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];[obj release];

Comment: The "Use ARC" counsel was undoubtedly just a side comment, not meant to be done in conjunction with the `release` code which is obviously unneeded with ARC, because you'll have a lot less of these routine memory management problems resulting from putting your `release` statements in the wrong place. You might, esp given that you're not using ARC, though, use Xcode's static analyzer ("Product" - "Analyze" or shift+command+B), which will highlight many routine memory management problems in your non-ARC code.

Comment: @Rob is perfectly correct !!!

Answer (score 1):

your object of class was Released then it access again that object who already released so you got this bad access error.
please read this following link Article for [Understanding EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Inventory *obj = [[[Inventory alloc] initWithNibName:@"Inventory" bundle:nil] autorelease]
```